# Graviton particles travelling backwards

Tags: time, antimatter, arrow-of-time

I know that time travelling backward  particles are anti-matter particles but what about graviton time travelling backward?

Comment: The graviton, if it exists, is its own antiparticle. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/273918/

Comment: Antimatter can be _represented_ in calculations as matter with the opposite charge and parity going backward in time. That does not mean that is what it _is_.

Answer (score 3):

As far as we know nothing travels backwards in time so antiparticles are not particles travelling backwards in time. If you want to learn more about this it is discussed in the question [Is anti-matter matter going backwards in time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/is-anti-matter-matter-going-backwards-in-time)

However an antiparticle does obey the same equations as a particle going backwards in time, so for example an electron moving backwards in time would behave like a positron. You ask what a graviton moving backwards in time would behave like, and the answer is a graviton. The graviton is its own antiparticle i.e. an antigraviton and graviton are the same particle, so a graviton moving backwards in time would just behave like a graviton. The same is true for the photon and the Higgs boson. All three particles are their own antiparticle.